# MODx 500 error on install?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have tried to install MODx on my new hosting, it uses PHP 5.5, but the problem is that i can not install any version, tried with latest, and even with 2.2, but no luck. Setup is working ok, but on final action in setup

**setup/index.php?action=summary**

I got

**500 Error
Site temporarily unavailable.**

I can not access manager, web, nothing, only can go in /setup and start install again??

In MODx error log i see the following

```
[2015-12-25 06:43:58] (ERROR @ /index.php) Error 42S02 executing statement: 
Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => 1146
    [2] => Table 'xxxxxxxx.modx_system_settings' doesn't exist
)

[2015-12-25 06:43:58] (FATAL) Could not load core MODX configuration!
```

Comment: What is the name of your host? Sometimes you will find in google an instruction for the installation on your host

Comment: loopia hosting, i donw have instructions

Comment: maybe you should call your host for help

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with activated MySQL strict mode. If you could disable this …

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, it looks like the Mysql table doesn't exists. Connect to your mysql with phpMyAdmin (usually hosting providers give you the link when registering/creating account). Check the database you entered in the setup and you should see all the tables regarding Modx. If they are not here, then there is something else going on.

Are you sure you selected "New install" and not "Upgrade modx" in step 2 on setup?